# padding not factored using ShapeDrawable and ArcShape

Tags: android

I am trying to set up a segmented circle inside another segmented circle using a `Canavs` in Android. I orginaly was using `draw.Arc()` but I need to use a lower API. I am using an `ArchShape` to create an arc, for the most part it works but when setting padding on the second circle, the padding isn't taking effect.

This is the first circle, works as expected. 
[image: First Circle]

When drawing the second circle it overrides the first, even with padding on. 
[image: Second Circle]

I tried offsetting the padding on the re-size for the second one and the padding isn't working. But you can see both are drawn. 
[image: Together]

This is my code with the offset padding on the re-size.

```
  Bitmap b;
    Canvas c;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();



        b = Bitmap.createBitmap(SIZE, SIZE, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        c = new Canvas(b);
        Paint p1 = new Paint();
        Paint p2 = new Paint();
        p1.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        p2.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);


        p1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        p2.setColor(Color.RED);
        SegmentCircle(0, p1, p2);

        p1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        p2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        SegmentCircle(50, p1, p2);


        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(b);



    }

    private final static int SIZE = 500;

    private void SegmentCircle(int padding, Paint p1, Paint p2){
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

            if ((i % 2) == 0){
                ArcShape shape = new ArcShape(i * 18, 18);
                ShapeDrawable d = new ShapeDrawable(shape);
                shape.resize(SIZE - (padding / 2), SIZE - (padding / 2));
                d.setPadding(padding,padding,padding,padding);
                shape.draw(c, p1);
            }else{
                ArcShape shape = new ArcShape(i * 18, 18);
                ShapeDrawable d = new ShapeDrawable(shape);
                shape.resize(SIZE - (padding / 2), SIZE - (padding / 2));
                d.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
                shape.draw(c, p2);
            }
        }
    }
```

I think it might be to do with the the fact I'm drawing the shape and not the `ShapeDrawable` but the `ShapeDrawable.Draw()` doesn't accept a Paint in the parameters, so I thought the shape would reference the `ShapeDrawable`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it, I didn't need to the `ShapeDrawable` or padding. I used translate to offset the canvas position.

```
Bitmap b;
    Canvas c;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();



        b = Bitmap.createBitmap(SIZE, SIZE, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        c = new Canvas(b);
        Paint p1 = new Paint();
        Paint p2 = new Paint();
        p1.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        p2.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);


        p1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        p2.setColor(Color.RED);
        SegmentCircle(0, p1, p2);

        p1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        p2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        SegmentCircle(50, p1, p2);


        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(b);



    }

    private final static int SIZE = 500;

    private void SegmentCircle(int padding, Paint p1, Paint p2){
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            ArcShape shape = new ArcShape(i * 18, 18);

            shape.resize(SIZE - padding, SIZE - padding );
            c.translate(padding / 2, padding / 2);

            if ((i % 2) == 0){
                shape.draw(c, p1);
            }else{

                shape.draw(c, p2);
            }

            c.translate(-(padding / 2), -(padding / 2));
        }
    }
```

[image]